# Printing onto a Static Document with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, pdf, printing

My father is a used car salesman and I am going to write him an applicaion that he can type in all of the information regarding the car being sold, buyer and himself to save him some time.

The only real challenge is that there are three static documents that I need to print out and on those documents I need to place information such as Buyer Name, Car Make/Model/Year, etc. How would someone recommend I do this? Ideally I would want to scan the static (blank) documents, the somehow put text boxes around the empty spots on the page in which a piece of information goes (like buyer's name) and then print it.

Does anyone have a decent methdology for this? Is there a way to create maybe a PDF document with text boxes that are blank, and then I open the document inserting informationg into the text boxes programmatically?

I prefer to write the solution in C#, I'm going to gather the data via C# but the only thing I'm having trouble with is the printing aspect.

Thanks,

Comment: You could scan the document as a bitmap, and print the bitmap along with the text you want to overlay on top of it with the PrintDocument class.  See the PrintPage, but the PrintDocument class has an example of how to print documents.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use the builtin Crystal Reports for Visual Studio since this will allow you to design the forms (as reports) and merge them with data.

There are a lot of resource available for getting started in this including:

[Getting Started (How Do I in Crystal Reports for Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225615%28v=vs.90%29)

and

[Generate a Report using Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166291/Generate-a-report-using-Crystal-Reports-in-Visual)